# Logback log to different files from the same package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

I want to log into two different files, historic.log and applicative.log, from the same package that is com.authenticationservice.user.UserRequest.
In the historic.log file I want to log at info level and in the applicative.log I want to log at level error.

This is how I've done it, but it isn't working properly, only one of the two loggers works properly.

logback-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />

    <appender name="Console"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %white(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="HistoricLog"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/historic.log</file>
        <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/historicArchived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ApplicativeLog"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/applicative.log</file>
        <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/applicativeArchived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>

      <logger name="com.authenticationservice.user.UserRequest" level="info" additivity="false">
          <appender-ref ref="HistoricLog" />
      </logger>

      <logger name="com.authenticationservice.user.UserRequest" level="error" additivity="false">
          <appender-ref ref="ApplicativeLog" />
      </logger>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `additivity="false"` flag

Comment: I've tried it but it hasn't worked